# Does Psalm supprt @param-out for "this"?

Tags: php, psalm-php

Is it possible to manipulate phantom types in Psalm using `@param-out` for `this` or `self`? Example:

```php
/**
 * @template T
 */
class Foo
{
  /**
   * @param T $t
   */
  public function __construct($t)
  {
    $this->t = $t;
  }
  /**
   * WRONG:
   * @param-out Test<S> $this
   */
  public function test()
  {
    // Also this doesn't work:
    $this->t = new S();
  }
}
```

A use-case for this could be e.g. a file class with phantom type set to `Open` or `Closed`, and calling `$file->open();` changes `T` to `Open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There's a pull request about it that might or might not be merged, using `@param-self-out`.